# Binding one item in a collection based on an external variable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

If I have a collection of items on a model, how would I bind one item to fields in a view based on an external variable.

Say I have this model:

```
public class Element
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ElementData> Data { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ElementData CurrentData
    {
        get
        {
            if (Data == null)
                return null;

            ElementData data = Data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LanguageID == MyContext.Current.Language.ID);
            if (data == null)
                data = Data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LanguageID == MyContext.Current.DefaultLanguage.ID);

            return data;
        }
    }
}

public class ElementData
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Element")]
    public Guid ElementID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Language")]
    public Guid LanguageID { get; set; }

    public virtual Element Element { get; set; }
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CurrentData.ID)

<header class="editor-header">
    <div class="editor-title">                
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CurrentData.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CurrentData.Name)
    </div>
</header>
<hr />
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CurrentData.Content)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CurrentData.Content)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CurrentData.Content)
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Edit(Element element)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(element).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.Entry(element.CurrentData).State = EntityState.Modified; // Exception here as CurrentData is null
        db.SaveChanges();

        return "success";
    }
}
```

I'm posting this data back using this ajax:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("submit", "form", function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#result').html(result);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

The model is valid in the controller but, obviously, it's not repopulating my ElementData list as it can't do that via CurrentData. I'm suspecting that I just don't know how to properly bind one item from my element data list but I can't find a guide that allows me to pick out one single item from a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here was to create a much better model. I've used a view model and resolved this in the controller. Lesson learnt.